# Loop through incrementing custom fields

Tags: custom-field, loop, query, get-posts

I created 4 custom fields for a specific page.

**Field type:**

- Post Object (I grab thumbnails and titles from the posts)

**Field names:**

- featured_content_1
- featured_content_2
- featured_content_3
- featured_content_4

Right now I display the content in a list like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <?php 
            $featuredContentPostID = get_field('featured_content_1')->ID;
            $selectedFeaturedContent = get_post( $featuredContentPostID );
        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink($featuredContentPostID) ); ?>">
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $featuredContentPostID, 'thumbnail' ); ?>
            <span><?php echo $selectedFeaturedContent->post_title ?></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <?php 
            $featuredContentPostID = get_field('featured_content_2')->ID;
            $selectedFeaturedContent = get_post( $featuredContentPostID );
        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink($featuredContentPostID) ); ?>">
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $featuredContentPostID, 'thumbnail' ); ?>
            <span><?php echo $selectedFeaturedContent->post_title ?></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

1. How can I loop through the fields and display the content without having to deplicate it?
2. Is it best practice to name them the same? i.e "featured_content"
3. One last question - how could I put a flag on one of them from the
   custom field section so I could promote one of them?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I've added a new field (select box) to my set of custom fields :

- featured_content_1
- featured_content_2
- featured_content_3
- featured_content_4
- promoted_content

How could I retrieve the value of that Select field ('promoted_content')?

**UPDATE 2**

Solution to promote content & add an 'active' class to LI:

```
<?php
    for ($i=1; $i<=4; $i++) {
        $fieldName = 'featured_content_' . $i;
        $featuredContentPostID = get_field($fieldName)->ID;
        $selectedFeaturedContent = get_post( $featuredContentPostID );
        $promoted_content = get_field('promoted');
        ?>
        <li class="<?php if($promoted_content == $fieldName) { echo 'active'; }?>">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink($featuredContentPostID) ); ?>">
                        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $featuredContentPostID, 'thumbnail' ); ?>
                        <span><?php echo $selectedFeaturedContent->post_title ?></span>
                </a>
        </li>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I loop through the fields and display the content without having to deplicate it?

This for loop will cycle through the four field names to avoid duplication.

```
<?php
    for ($i=1; $i<=4; $i++) {
            $fieldName = 'featured_content_' . $i;
            $featuredContentPostID = get_field($fieldName)->ID;
            $selectedFeaturedContent = get_post( $featuredContentPostID );
            ?>
            <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink($featuredContentPostID) ); ?>">
                            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $featuredContentPostID, 'thumbnail' ); ?>
                            <span><?php echo $selectedFeaturedContent->post_title ?></span>
                    </a>
            </li>
            <?php
    }
?>
```

> Is it best practice to name them the same? i.e "featured_content"

Normally, I think you're better off with more specific names - however if the plugin is adding a more "generic" feature (i.e. allowing the user to feature four arbitrary bits of content like this) then this naming scheme is fine.

> One last question - how could I put a flag on one of them from the custom field section so I could promote one of them?

I'd add another custom field, perhaps a drop-down named something like `promoted_content_field`. There, the user can choose which of the four to promote (or none). Then, in the loop above just add a check to see if the field that's currently being processed is the promoted one chosen in `promoted_content_field`

Comment: Hi Aric, thanks for your answer. I made updated to my question. How would you retrieve the select option (promoted_content)?

Comment: I believe this should work: `get_post('promoted_content');`

Comment: As suggested, I added a check to see if the field currently processed is the promoted one - if so I add a class 'active' to the LI

Comment: Hi Aric, didn't want to hijack this Post so I created another question related to this post. In case you'd have a second to take a look. Thanks again. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/204958/combine-two-different-loops