# Loop through two different sets of custom fields

Tags: custom-field, loop, pages, get-posts, meta-query

1. I created a Custom Field ('custom_name') to allow content editors to specify a 'custom_name' (different from the title of the page) to any post created:

   - custom_name - (Field type --> 'text')
2. For a specific page I created 4 Custom Fields that lets the content editor pick 4 articles he would like to feature:

   - featured_content_1 (Field type --> 'Post Object')
   - featured_content_2
   - featured_content_3
   - featured_content_4
   - promoted

On that page I display the featured content as a list of thumbnails:

```
<?php
    for ($i=1; $i<=4; $i++) {
        $fieldName = 'featured_content_' . $i;
        $featuredContentPostID = get_field($fieldName)->ID;
        $selectedFeaturedContent = get_post( $featuredContentPostID );
        $promoted_content = get_field('promoted');
        ?>
        <li class="<?php if($promoted_content == $fieldName) { echo 'active'; }?>">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink($featuredContentPostID) ); ?>">
                        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $featuredContentPostID, 'thumbnail' ); ?>
                        <span><?php echo $selectedFeaturedContent->post_title ?></span>
                </a>
        </li>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

I manage to query and display the 'artist_name' in a different loop:

```
<?php   
    $artistNameArgs = array(
        'meta_key' => 'artist_name'
    );
    $artistName = new WP_Query( $artistNameArgs );
?>

<ul>
<?php if( $artistName->have_posts() ): ?>
    <?php while ( $artistName->have_posts() ) : $artistName->the_post(); ?>
        <li><?php the_field('artist_name'); ?></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>       
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

How can I combine the two so the 'artist_name' appears in the LI of the thumbnails LIs ?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I managed to make it work. Here is my updated code:

```
<?php
        for ($i=1; $i<=4; $i++) {
            $fieldName = 'featured_content_' . $i;
            $featuredContents = get_field($fieldName);
            $featuredContentPostID = get_field($fieldName)->ID;
            $selectedFeaturedContent = get_post( $featuredContentPostID );
            $promoted_content = get_field('promoted');
            ?>
            <li class="<?php if($promoted_content == $fieldName) { echo 'active'; }?>">
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink($featuredContentPostID) ); ?>">
                            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $featuredContentPostID, 'thumbnail' ); ?>
                            <span>
                                <?php
                                    foreach($featuredContents as $featuredContent){
                                        the_field('content_name', $featuredContent);
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </span>
                    </a>
            </li>
            <?php
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question literally doesn't quite sound like "combining" loops, that's usually different thing in WP terminology.

Following it literally you already know the part that outputs artist name you want — `the_field('artist_name')`.

What probably confuses it in first context is that it's not *really* a normal WP loop. Note how that call doesn't specify *which post* artist name should be for? That conventionally comes from global post if omitted. You are not setting up post globals at all in your first snippet.

Since `the_field()` isn't even WP function I assume you use one of numerous custom fields frameworks. You will have to consult its documentation how to retrieve the data for a specific post, provided by ID explicitly.

Comment: For the Custom Fields I use the Advanced Custom Fields plugin

Comment: Hi Rarst, I updated my question with the latest I've done so far